# Vue.js and .NET WEBAPI2 POST from Axios 405 or 415 error

Tags: c#, rest, vue.js, asp.net-web-api2, axios

I'm having trouble POSTing to my WEBAPI.

My code for my ASP.NET WEBAPI is as follows:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Test")]
   public class TestController : ApiController
   {
       // GET: api/Test
       [Route]
       public IEnumerable<string> Get()
       {
           return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
       }

       [Route]
       public void Post([FromBody]string value)
       {
           Debugger.Break();
       }
```

The calls from my Vue.js app via axios are as follows:

```
   PostTest(){
       alert("Post Test Starting");
       var data = new FormData();
       data.set('value','test');
       //var data = {'value': 'test'};
       this.CallAxios('post', 'http://localhost:10000/api/Test/', data, axiosHeaders);
   },
   CallAxios(callMethod, callURL, callData, callHeaders)
   {
     axios({
       method: callMethod,
       url: callURL,
       data: callData,
       headers: callHeaders
     }).then((response) => {
       alert(response.data)
     })
   }
```

My Content-Type for all requests is set to application/json

If I call the PostTest Vue method using the FormData section and leaving the [FromBody] attribute on the .NET API Post method I receive the following 415 "Unsupported Media Type" error:

> {"Message":"The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is
>   not supported for this resource.","ExceptionMessage":"No
>   MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'String'
>   from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.",

So even though I specified application/json for the Content-Type it is still coming across as multipart/form-data

If I switch the Vue.js code to use the "var data = {'value': 'test'}" and I remove the [FromBody] attribute from the .NET Post parameter I receive the following 405 "Method Not Allowed" error:

> {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method
>   'POST'."}

I've been fighting with this for a while. It seems I can do one of the following options:

1. Using the FormData vue call, how do I get by the 415 error with the multipart/form-data issue?
2. Using a JSon string how do I support the POST verb in the API call?

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to accomplish this (neither of them will use FormData)

1) **Sending as Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded** . To do this you'll need to URL-encode the parameter with a library like qs.  However, notice this special WebAPI caveat (empty key name)

```
import qs from 'qs';
let myValue = 'FontSpace'
let options = {
    url: '/api/fonts'
    , method: 'post'
    , data: qs.stringify({ '': myValue })
}
let response = await this.$http(options)
```

If you inspect the request in devtools you'll see the parameter gets encoded as

> =FontSpace

2) **Sending as Content-Type application/json** . To do this you'll JSON.stringify JUST the value (no key) and also explicitly specify the content-type in the headers

```
let myValue = 'FontSpace'
let options = {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    , url: '/api/fonts'
    , method: 'post'
    , data: JSON.stringify(myValue)
}
let response = await axios(options)
```

Inspect in devtools and you'll see the the parameter gets JSON encoded

> "FontSpace"

As long as your encoding and your content-type matches, WebAPI2 will accept your request.

---

[This documentation was helpful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

> When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header to select a formatter. In this example, the content type is "application/json" and the request body is a raw JSON string (not a JSON object).